# React Final Form: has a value existed?

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

How is it possible to check has a value already existed using React Final Form? I'm interested in the general approach. Also, be thankful for some links, etc, because could find nothing relevant.

Now details:

1. I have a form: a text input "User name" and a button "Submit".
2. I type a value (let say, "John") and press "Submit".
3. The value is saved into a database and becomes to display on my web page.
4. The input field is cleared and I am able to enter the new value.
5. I'm entering "John" again.

I should get an error message "Such name has already existed" once I moved the focus out of the field, or click on the "Submit" button.

Answer (score 1):

You'd generally accomplish this by doing a preflight request to the server via [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Send the field value(s) over whenever you do validation (e.g. on change or on blur) and have the server report back any issues (e.g. "Name already taken").

Comment: Hey, Ray, how do you think: should I send the fetch one time when a page is rendering (and then append the entered values to local storage) or it is better send queries to a server each time while the validation executed?

Comment: Local storage is 1) only going to work for the current browser, 2) get out of sync with the actual database, and 3) break if you have too many names. Send the request to the server whenever you feel it's appropriate to validate. In a real app you'll want to [debounce](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function) the validation to avoid flooding the server with requests.

Answer (score 0):

Implement some checking logic In the POST request. Before you write the logic to add the user to the database, check If a user with that username already exists, and If It does, return an error. It also depends on the database you are using how they handle searching for documents.

If its MongoDB you need to use the .find() method and find by username. If you find a matching username, return an error saying to enter a unique username.